# Redis atomic pop and add to sorted set, BRPOPLPUSH equivalent

Tags: redis

I have one redis list "waiting" and one redis list "partying".

I have a long running process that safely blocks on the "waiting" list item to come along, and then pops it and pushes it onto the "partying" list atomically using [`BRPOPLPUSH`](https://redis.io/commands/brpoplpush). Awesome.

Users in the "waiting" list are repeatedly querying "am I in the "partying" list yet?", but there is no fast (i.e. < O(n)) method of checking if a user is in a redis list. You have to grab the whole list and loop through it.

So I'm resorting to switching from a redis list to a redis sorted set, with the 'score' as the unix timestamp of when they joined the "waiting" sorted set. I can blocking pop on the lowest score (user at the head of the queue). Using sorted sets, I can use `ZSCORE` to check in O(1) time if they're on either list, so it's looking hopeful.

How can I perform the nice atomic equivalent of `BRPOPLPUSH` on sorted sets?
It's like I need a mythical `BZRPOPMIN` & `ZADD`= `BZRPOPMINZADD`. If the process dies between these two, a user will effectively be disappeared from both sets.

Looking into `MULTI` `EXEC` [transactions](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) in redis, they are not what they appear to be at first glance, they're more like 'pipelines', in that I can't get the result of the first command (`BZRPOPMIN`) and feed it into the second command (`ZADD`). I'm very suspicious of putting the blocking `BZRPOPMIN` into the `MULTI` too, am I right to be?

Comment: I can't think of a good answer, offhand. As soon as you want to use blocking commands you're very limited, since Redis has few of them and you lose the ability to compose atomic blocks out of other commands (transactions or scripts). So one approach is to poll rather than block. Better advice might be just to ignore the scary looking O(n) and stick to your original design. Redis is very fast, and complicating your architecture to avoid performance bottlenecks you haven't actually hit is a classic anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I've gone with lists and O(n), that was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I perform the nice atomic equivalent of BRPOPLPUSH on sorted sets?

Sorry, you can't. We actually discussed this when the ZPOP family was added and decided against it: "However I'm not for the BZPOPZADD part, because instead experience with lists shown that this is not a good idea in general, unfortunately, and that that adding safety of message processing may be used other means. The worst thing abut BZPOPZADD and BRPOPLPUSH and so forth are the cascading effects, they create a lot of problems in replication for instance, and our BRPOPLPUSH replication is still not correct in certain ways (we can talk about it if you want)." (ref: https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/4879#issuecomment-389116241)

> I'm very suspicious of putting the blocking BZRPOPMIN into the MULTI too, am I right to be?

Definitely, and blocking commands can't be called inside a transaction anyway.